Interpreting one of the several expressions of the pushfoward of a vector field on a Lie group (Prof Schuller lecture)
Given a vector field $X$ and a left-translation function $l_g$ by an element of the Lie group $g \in G$ defined as $l_g(h)=gh,$ and an arbitrary function $f$
$$X_h(f \circ l_g) = X(f) (g h)$$
seems to indicate that the $X_h$ (which is a single vector at the point $h$) applied to the composition $f \circ l_g$ is the same as the entire vector field $X$ acting on the function $f$ and evaluating at the point $gh$.
Why is the LHS of the equation correct? I am missing some expression of the pushforward - an $*$ somewhere: $X_h$ is the vector at the point $h$ of the vector field $X$. $l_g$ just multiples $g$ times $h$ as per the group operation, resulting in the point $gh$, i.e. $f \circ l_g$. So we look at a function at the point $gh$, but we apply the vector at the point $h$ (i.e. $X_h$). How can we apply the vector at the point $h$ to something in the point $gh$?
Source of the equation in here

The expression $X_h(f\circ l_g)$ is considered as a tangent vector $X_h\in T_h G$ at the point $h$ applied to a function $(f\circ l_g) \in C^\infty(G)$. So, in the lecture:
$$X_h(f\circ l_g) = \bigl((l_g)_{*,h} X_h\bigr) (f) = X_{gh}(f) = \bigl(X(f)\bigr) (gh), $$
where the first equality is the usual definition of the push-forward.
For a smooth map $\rho\colon\, M\to N$ and a vector $X_p\in T_p M$, the push-forward $\rho_{*,p} X_p \in T_{\rho(p)}N$ is a vector at $\rho(p)\in N$ defined via the property:
$$(\rho_{*,p} X_p)(f) = X_p (f\circ \rho) \qquad \forall f\in C^\infty(N).$$
Here, on the LHS, a vector at $\rho(p)\in N$ is applied to a function $f\in C^\infty(N)$, and on the RHS, a vector at $p \in M$ is applied to a function $f\circ \rho \in C^\infty(M)$.
So, in this example, $\rho = l_g\colon\, G\to G$, which not only maps $h\mapsto gh$ but is a map defined on the entire $G$.
